# InternetCombineUrlW and InternetCanonicalizeUrlW in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

What can I use in Linux С++ to implement the logic of these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe you can have a look at how they are implemented in Wine? Since building it from scratch could be prone to bugs.

**EDIT**

I actually did look at it, I took the latest Wine sources from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/), found the `InternetCombineUrlW` in `dlls/wininet/internet.c`, and the impmenetation was calling `UrlCombineW` which resides in `dlls/shlwapi/url.c`. Since it still references other WinApi functions implemented in Wine, maybe it makes sense to trim the files and just use them in your project directly, instead of trying to copy the parts needed.

Comment: I had this  thought a little earlier and already did, but thx anyway